# Can no longer install WordPress on MAMP- "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class wpdb"

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp

I've been developing WordPress sites for a long time on my local MAMP server.  Now all of a sudden, it won't let me create any new sites.  Whenever I set up a new one, instead of running the install script I get:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class
>   wpdb in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/[my_site]/wp-includes/wp-db.php
>   on line 52

This happens with all WordPress versions.  I cannot thing of anything that would have caused this.  I've done everything short of re-install MAMP.  Does anyone have any ideas?  I'm desperate at this point..

Comment: Close voter PLEASE have the decency to explain why- this is a critical issue for me

Comment: The close voter likely felt this belongs at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Does that mean we're not allowed to ask WordPress questions on SO, even if they're legitimate programming questions?  Why the fragmentation?

Comment: When there's a specific StackExchange site for a question, that's generally the better place for it. If nothing else, you'll likely get better answers on such a specialized site.

Comment: Don't like it- The whole point of SO is the critical mass of expertise- fragmentation seems to defeat that

Comment: This discussion belongs in meta.stackoverflow.com..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround fix is to wrap the wpdp class in `wp-includes/wp-db.php` in the following:

**Line 52:**

```
if(class_exists('wpdb') != true)
{

class wpdb {
...
}

}
```

This solved the install issue- You could probably remove it after that, although it can't hurt to leave it I guess.

Still don't understand why this problem has popped up- If someone has an explanation I'd be eager to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the include path for php. It's likely that a second instance of wordpress is on the include path and is therefore conflicting with the one you're trying to load. It's also possible that a different package on the include path has a class called wpdb and is therefore causing a conflict.

Comment: Thanks but I don't follow- I often run many instances of WordPress at the same time.  Where should I be checking the include path?

Comment: check phpinfo() for the include path since it's a global problem. _Something_ in that include path contains a class called wpdb. I had a similar problem once when I upgraded my version of php and pear and all of a sudden my authenticate.php class was generating the same error as yours because a duplicate class name was in the pear library. My options were to change the pear library or rename mine, so I just went with renaming mine. For you, it might be that whatever thing is conflicting isn't necessary and you can remove it safely.

Answer (score 0):

`wpdb` is being created again some where, if this happened all of a sudden i suggest that you disable any plugins you've recently added. Or even better do a global find for the term `class wpdb` and see if that appears within more than 1 file. Also, check your functions.php file for a loop that might be loading `wp-db.php` more than once.

Comment: @dotty- the strange thing is, though this may have been triggered by a plugin I was fooling with, it now happens on all new, completely clean, plugin-less WordPress instances I try to install, even after restarting MAMP server, rebooting computer, etc... Don't understand how that issue could persist

Comment: How about installing it in a different directory? And when you say `instance`, are you using wordpress MS?

Comment: @dotty- By instance I just mean a new WordPress site, not MS- And yeah, tried installing in diff directory- didn't help.  It's almost as if something got corrupted at the MAMP server level...